# Files Not Appearing in S3 File Storage Gateway Bucket

Tags: storage, nfs, amazon-s3, files, image

I created an **AWS S3 File Storage Gateway** and mounted it to a Linux server on-prem. On that same server where the file gateway is mounted I have a separate NFS share mounted. My goal is to copy files from the NFS share to the file gateway share - so NFS mount to NFS mount.

For some reason though the files copy over (if I am on the Linux server I can see them in the directory I created) but I can't see them in the S3 Bucket when I access via a *browser*. The files I am copying over are *VM images* and I am copying the files over using a shell script.

I tried waiting a few hours to see if the file would appear in the bucket in the browser - each one was 3-4gb and it was three files total, but nothing shows up. Any idea what the issue is or what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

There was a pending update that needed to be applied to S3 File Storage Gateway services from Amazon. After applying this update files started showing up.